# SVG basics: moving the endpoint of a line

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I'd like to create a straight line in SVG that is anchored at one point. When the user clicks and drags the other endpoint, that endpoint follows their cursor. I'm using `snap.svg` for this.

My idea to do this was to first draw a line:

```
var line = paper.line( 300, 250, 450, 150 );

line.attr({
  stroke: "#000",
  strokeWidth: 5,
  strokeLinecap:"round"
});
```

then create a controlling circle that I track drag events on. In the drag callback I would update the `x2` and `y2` properties of the line using the `dx` and `dy` arguments passed.

The first thing I noticed is that simply setting the attributes causing things to blow up. I'm not entirely sure I understand why this is, but it seems like it might be the case that my callback is called repeatedly before it has a chance to run. Then when it 'catches up' to itself it somehow overshoots. I'm not too sure.

Anyway, through Googling I was able to determine that using the transform property on the controlling circle would allow me to emulate the default `drag` method:

```
var move = function(dx,dy) {
  // This appends the new transform to the original
  this.attr({
    transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
  });
} 

// Maybe this saves the current transform if it hasn't happened yet?
var start = function() {
  this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}

var circle = paper.circle( 450, 150, 5 );

circle.drag(move, start);
```

At this point, I'm stuck. I can't use the same `transform` trick for the `x2` and `y2` attributes of the line. And if I set them directly I get that overshooting problem.

SVG pros – any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: If you still have a problem after the answer below, I would post up a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks @Ian...the answer below did fix things for me. I appreciate your clarifying comment on that answer by the way :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made sample code.
http://jsdo.it/defghi1977/kxK1

---

```
var paper = Snap().attr({width:"500",height:"500"});
var line = paper.line(0,0,100,100)
    .attr({strokeWidth:5,stroke:"black",strokeLinecap:"round"});
var circle = paper.circle(100,100,10).attr({fill:"red"});
var x,y;
circle.drag(function(dx,dy){
    circle.attr({cx:+x+dx,cy:+y+dy});
    line.attr({x2:+x+dx,y2:+y+dy});
},function(){
    x = line.attr("x2");
    y = line.attr("y2");
},function(){});
```

Comment: Interesting, @defghi1977...so is `dx` equal to the total movement of the thing since the start of the drag, and **not** the difference since the last time the onmove fn was called?

Comment: Nope, its the difference from the starting point of the drag.

Comment: Thanks, @Ian! This makes a lot of sense. I was misinterpreting how the docs described `dx` and `dy`.